# Appending rows of dataframe containing duplicate columns from extract regex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:
[image]

I would like to merge dd2 and dd1 columns, mm1 and mm2 columns yyyy1 and yyyy2 columns and so on. If there is a value in dd1 there is no value in dd2. Could someone please suggest a pandorable way to do this?

I ended up with this format using pandas.Series.str.extract('regex')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py#L776):

```
d = {'mm':df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('mm')],
     'dd':df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('dd')],
     'yyyy':df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('yyyy')]}

df = pd.lreshape(df, d)
```

Or [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=['mm','dd','yyyy'], i=['index'], j='DROPME')
       .dropna(how='all')
       .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or extract text with numbers to `Multiindex` and then [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
a = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('(dd|mm|yyyy)(\d+)', expand=True).values.tolist()
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a)
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response! The wide_to_long method worked for me!!

Comment: Not only the merge, wide_to_long also handles NaN values as expected and renames the columns.

Comment: Super ;) I add another solution, it should handle NaNs too.

Comment: I checked out the three solutions and the wide_to_long is the easiest to use, crisp and does what is needed. Good to know the other verbose solutions in case more flexibility is needed by someone though!!